# How to embed PlaceAutocompleteFragment in android app

Tags: android, google-places-api

I want to implement `placeautocompletefragment` in my Android app. I am trying to use the instructions at [this url](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) but it is showing:

> can not resolve symbol for placeautocompletefragment

[Example of what I want to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPDA0.png)

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
```

getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

Comment: 1) can u post your code here.   <br/>   2)has the placeautocompletefragment been imported to ur activity

Comment: have you check my bellow answer...

Comment: check my answer....let me knw if you have any problem...

Comment: placeautocompletefragment is not going to imported.there is any library to add for this fragment.

Comment: placeautocomplete is also not importing.

Comment: check the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718624/placeautocomplete-widget-on-mapview-fragment

Answer (score 1):

Just Follow bellow Procedure but before that make sure you have added google library and api key

1.Add bellow function on you button click

```
private void openAutocompleteActivity() {
        try {
            // The autocomplete activity requires Google Play Services to be available. The intent
            // builder checks this and throws an exception if it is not the case.
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                    .build(mActivity);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // Indicates that Google Play Services is either not installed or not up to date. Prompt
            // the user to correct the issue.
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(mActivity, e.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                    0 /* requestCode */).show();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // Indicates that Google Play Services is not available and the problem is not easily
            // resolvable.
            String message = "Google Play Services is not available: " +
                    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(e.errorCode);

            Log.e("Tag", message);
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

2.then add this function

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the user's selected place from the Intent.
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(mActivity, data);
                Log.i("TAG", "Place Selected: " + place.getName());

                LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
                latitude = latLng.latitude;
                longitude = latLng.longitude;

                Log.v(ApplicationsConstants.LoginDetails.LATITUDE, "" + latitude);
                Log.v(ApplicationsConstants.LoginDetails.LONGITUDE, "" + longitude);

                tvCity.setText(place.getName());
                Utils.saveDataToPreferences(mActivity, ApplicationsConstants.LoginDetails.CITY, "" + place.getName());
                Utils.saveDataToPreferences(mActivity, ApplicationsConstants.LoginDetails.LATITUDE, "" + latitude);
                Utils.saveDataToPreferences(mActivity, ApplicationsConstants.LoginDetails.LONGITUDE, "" + longitude);

            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(mActivity, data);
                Log.e("TAG", "Error: Status = " + status.toString());
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Indicates that the activity closed before a selection was made. For example if
                // the user pressed the back button.
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you haven't figured it out yet. Then remember: You need to setup Google Play Services first before using it. Setup instructions are [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

A point to note is that you don't have to include the entire google play services library like this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
```

You can include only the section that you need in your case it is Places.
So it will be:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.1'
```

A point to note when looking up resources on google is that earlier Places was bundled with Location services. So the resources on internet would be using them like this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:X.X.X'
```

However, THIS IS NOT THE CASE ANYMORE. Now Places and Location are separate.