# Android PlaceAutocompleteFragment not opening Fragment

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have added the PlaceAutocompleteFragment in this way -

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
    autocompleteFragment.setHint("");
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Place: " + place.getLatLng());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.i("TAG", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

Also added in the dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```

And in the manifest

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

**Now when I am clicking on the search icon I nothing is opening not getting any error in log also. I am not sure what is the thing I am doing wrong.**

Comment: did you enable location service from the developer console?

Comment: yes like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34416818/2036992

Comment: Strange. It should work seeing nothing is wrong with your approach. Check your api key and the permissions in your manifest to see if anything is wrong.

Comment: check the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718624/placeautocomplete-widget-on-mapview-fragment